# Trying to scrape .aspx site in python but it won't POST

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm attempting to scrape https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx using python 3's urllib and then parse it with BeautifulSoup. However, despite setting each of the input fields, the POST request merely returns the same page. It should redirect to https://www.idfpr.com/Applications/ProfessionProfile/ProfileSearchResults.aspx when the fields are populated and the search button is hit, but it doesn't.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import socket, ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ssl_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

    page_html = ''
    get_req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx',
                                     headers={
                                        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                                        # 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                                        # 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
                                    })
    try:
        page_html = urllib.request.urlopen(get_req,
                                           context=ssl_context
                                           ).read()
    except socket.timeout:
        print("Request timed out. Moving on.")
        exit(1)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
    except ssl.CertificateError as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)

    soup_dummy = BeautifulSoup(
        page_html,
        'html5lib'
    )

    # parse and retrieve two vital form values
    lastfocus = soup_dummy.select("#__LASTFOCUS")[0]['value']
    viewstate = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    viewstategen = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
    eventvalidation = soup_dummy.findAll("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__EVENTVALIDATION"})[0]['value']
    eventargument = soup_dummy.select('#__EVENTARGUMENT')[0]['value']

    # build input list of doctors
    doctors = [(0,"AKRAMI","CYRUS")]

    for doctor in doctors:  # iterate over doctors and search for them on the IL site

        formData = (
            ('__LASTFOCUS', lastfocus),
            ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
            ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR', viewstategen),
            ('__EVENTTARGET', 'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Search'),
            ('__EVENTARGUMENT', eventargument),
            ('__EVENTVALIDATION', eventvalidation),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$LastName', doctor[1]),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$FirstName', doctor[2]),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlCounty', '0'),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$City', ''),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlSpecialty', '0'),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$SpecialtyKeyword', ''),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlHospitals', '0'),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Search', 'Search'),
            ('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Clear', 'Clear')
        )

        encodedFields = urllib.parse.urlencode(formData).encode('ascii')
        # second HTTP request with form data
        post_req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx',
                                          data=encodedFields,
                                          headers={
                                            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                            # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                                            # 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                                            # 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
                                        })
        page_html = urllib.request.urlopen(post_req,
                                           data=encodedFields,
                                           context=ssl_context
                                           ).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html5lib")
```

What am I missing? My guess is it has something to do with `__EVENTTARGET`; I read that you need to set it to the submit button you want to hit, which in this case is `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Search`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I am unsure if it's contributing to your problem, but I'm pretty sure there's no value in transmitting a field for the Clear button like you're doing in your current code.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler when it failed to POST, my first assumption was that it was because I wasn't defining a value for each field. So I just made sure to grab the values on page load and then reassign them, just in case. So the error was there before I did that. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me. I am using `requests.Session()` though.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3; urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx', verify=False)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    vs = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    ev = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
    vsg = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')['value']
    data = {
  '__LASTFOCUS': '',
  '__VIEWSTATE':vs,
  '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vsg,
  '__EVENTTARGET': '',
  '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
  '__EVENTVALIDATION': ev,
    'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$LastName': 'Alaraj',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$FirstName': 'Ali ',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlCounty': '0',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$City': '',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlSpecialty': '0',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$SpecialtyKeyword': '',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$ddlHospitals': '0',
  'ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContentContainer$Search': 'Search'
}
    r = s.post('https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx',  data=data)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('#MainContent_MainContentContainer_gvwProfiles').text)
```

Comment: This worked, however I still don't understand why my previous code didn't. Did it have to do with form fields or how I handled SSL or something else entirely?

Comment: I setup an unverified SSL context. I wonder if it's because you didn't set `verify=False` on the POST request that yours worked and mine failed.

Comment: I don’t think that makes a difference though you can test easily enough